# Passwordless ssh config gives Server refused our key

Tags: server, 20.04, ssh, sshd

The keys are correct and sshd is configured correctly (read all previous SO questions for this problem). Any ideas? Trying to connect from Windows with Kitty (improved PuTTy)

Ubuntu Server 20.04 x64

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 asdf asdf 1475 Oct 18 15:08 /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

/etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf
Port 22
PermitRootLogin no 
MaxAuthTries 6
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
X11Forwarding yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem sftp  /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you know the keys are correct? How did you copy the public key to the server? Did you apply appropriately restrictive permissions to the authorized_keys file and its parent directory?

Comment: Copied them in 3 ways - generated by ssh, by hand and by copy/pasting them from Putty
Permissions are correct

Comment: Are you sure that you've enabled root login on the SSHd side?  in Ubuntu servers, `PermitRootLogin` is usually either denied or set to `prohibit-password` so it's Key only.  (You probably also should not have to SSH in as Root)

Comment: .... even if `PermitRootLogin` is set appropriately, I'm not sure it's permissible for root's keys to be owned by another user (or for keys to be owned by the "wrong" user in general). OTOH if you're trying to store `asdf`'s key(s) in `/root/.ssh` then I doubt that will work either

Comment: I can't connect with normal or `root` user. Added SSHd config for clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily found how to fix it by accident - seems sshd cannot read from `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` for unknown reason (have the same installation and configuration on another machine where passwordless ssh works).

I was forced to enter another file location in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
AuthorizedKeysFile      /home/asdf/authorized_keys/
```

instead of

```
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: can you accept your own answer please?

Comment: SO system says it's possible after two days